# collapsing table as a table row on click

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to collapse row of `tr.store-id` that contains a table in it when `tr.clickable` is clicked.

you can see my current issue **[presented in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sqLc9y4a/1/)**, the table seems to adjust itself to fit column `title1` after appearing!. I want the collapsable table to fit into the entire row not just one column.

I have tried changing the `.collapse`'s `display` property to values as `table-row` and such but did not work out. Could some one please tell me what the issue is?

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    tr.collapse.in {
      display: table-row;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">title1</th>
          <th scope="col">title2</th>
          <th scope="col">title3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".store-id" class="clickable">
          <td>hi there</td>
          <td>hi there</td>
          <td>hi there</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse store-id">
          <td colspan="3">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Links to third party sites are not acceptable.

Comment: @Rob, **I want the collapsable table to fit into the entire row not just one column**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap sets the property `display: block !important` when it adds the `.show` class to the element; while you can override this, maybe it would be better to find a way to be more specific to avoid changing Bootstrap classes.

Also: I noticed on your code that you are using Bootstrap 3's CSS, but BS4's JS, you should make sure you are using the correct imports for the right version, either both v3 or v4

Check the example:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    tr.show {
      display: table-row !important;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">title1</th>
          <th scope="col">title2</th>
          <th scope="col">title3</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>

        <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".store-id" class="clickable">
          <td>hi there</td>
          <td>hi there</td>
          <td>hi there</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="collapse store-id">
          <td colspan="3">
            <table class="table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">#</th>
                  <th scope="col">First</th>
                  <th scope="col">Last</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                  <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>Mark</td>
                  <td>Otto</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                  <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Jacob</td>
                  <td>Thornton</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                  <td>@fat</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: your answer works perfectly for me. thanks a lot sir :)

Comment: I'm just 24 :( lol but you're welcome; take notice of the Bootstrap version issue, make sure you use the same for all the imports to avoid any odd behaviors in the future

Comment: no problems young master ;), I took note about the bootstrap version. thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `display: table-row;` and not `display: block` on the `<tr>` when showing.

Comment: this is how my code is at the moment.. yet still not working :/